# If $\sum|a_n|$ = s then s = |$\sum a_n$|?

Tags: calculus

If $\sum|a_n|$ = s, then does it follow that s = |$\sum a_n$|?Justify your answer. What can be said?

which I think it is not true since |$\sum a_n$|<=$\sum|a_n|$ but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Try $n=2$, $a_1=1$ and $a_2=-1$.

Comment: oh , thanks for that

Comment: This is the "in-" part of the so-called _triangle inequality_.